# Ionic navCtrl.push opens new session of page but I need already opened one

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

In my Ionic app, I have a page to create `invoice`. I am making an invoice and in middle of it I need to open `statement of accounts`.

Now, if from `statement of accounts` I press the back button, my **partially filled** `invoice` form opens back without any loss of data.

But, if I open `invoice` form from the menu, it opens a new black session of the same form.

I want it to open the already opened, partially filled `invoice` form.

This is how I am calling the page from my `app.html` page:

```ts
<ion-item class="DropDown-Expand" menuClose (click)="nav.push(page.StatacPage)">
  <ion-icon name="document"></ion-icon><span>Ledger</span>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well then check if your invoice page is already on the navControllers stack and either pop to it (if it already exists in the navControllers stack) or push a new instance of it (if it does not exist in the navControllers stack).

The code for a method doing this might look something like this (assuming `this.navCtrl` holds an instance of NavController, further infos on injecting it can be found [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/#injecting-navcontroller)):

```ts
 moveTo(pageToMoveTo: Page): void {
    let views = this.navCtrl.getViews();
    let viewToMoveTo = views.find((viewController) => viewController.instance instanceof pageToMoveTo);
    if (viewToMoveTo === undefined) {
      //If the page is not yet on the navControllers stack, push it
      this.navCtrl.push(pageToMoveTo);
    } else {
      //If the page is on the stack, find the pages index
      let indexToMoveTo = this.navCtrl.getByIndex(viewToMoveTo.index);
      //And pop to this index
      this.navCtrl.popTo(indexToMoveTo);
    }
}
```

In your HTML you should be able to use it like this:

```ts
<ion-item class="DropDown-Expand" menuClose (click)="moveTo(page.StatacPage)">
  <ion-icon name="document"></ion-icon><span>Ledger</span>
</ion-item>
```

---

For further information on how the NavController works, refer to the [NavControllers docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/).

Comment: alright, i'll try to implement this and get back if i stuck somewhere

Comment: Any update on this? Were you able to implement this or are you facing trouble?